# Jquery UI: How to add icons to autocomplete results?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I was wondering if there is a way to add Jquery UI icons to the Jquery UI autocomplete results. My results are of 3 different categories and I wanted to make that clear by using icons.

I already recieve that category identification from the server as a number from 1 to 3 and I'm able to use it.

I also did put icons in the results but they were (ugly) custom icons. What I wanted to know is if there is an easy way to put the jquery ui built in icons in the results.

By now, I am putting the icons this way:

```
$("#input").autocomplete(source:"serveradress")
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var image = "<img src=\"images/icon_" + item.category + ".png\" class=\"icon\" />";
        var itemhtml = "<a> + image + item.value + "</a>";
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( itemhtml )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Comment: If anyone is using this code - make sure that you change `.data("autocomplete")` to `.data("ui-autocomplete")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in this:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span>
```

And I had to terminate it with

```
</span>
```

instead of self terminating the tag, it was causing issues for some reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just had to create a class to make the icons "inline-block"